# Jupyter (iPython Notebook) interface strange white bar at bottom of screen

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I recently installed iPython notebook (which looks like it has formally transitioned over to Jupyter) in a miniconda Python 3.4 environment. When I launch the interface, I have a huge white bar at the bottom of my screen that serves no purpose (see attached). What is the origin of this issue, and how may I resolve it? It looks like I'm running the latest conda version of all the dependencies.

I am running OSX Yosemite and the latest version of Chrome.

**Edit:** The exact same issue occurs when I open the notebook in Safari, which I do not ever use as a browser (and so I would expect it to have default settings). (See Figure 2) The issue does not occur if I open a remotely-hosted notebook, like the demos on [tmpnb](http://tmpnb.org) (See Figure 3)

Jupyter interface on Chrome with local host:
[image: Jupyter interface white bar Chrome]

Jupyter interface on Safari with local host:
[image: Jupyter interface white bar Safari]

Jupyter interface on Chrome with remote host:
[image: Jupyter interface with remote host]

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your chrome settings.

Comment: I cannot reproduce here on osx/chrome

Comment: Thank you @m170897017 and cel for your interest. I've added information to the question showing that the problem also occurs in Safari (which I don't use and which I would expect to  have default settings). The problem does not occur when I open a remotely-hosted notebook (second screenshot). Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was subtle and it was ultimately my fault. The previous version of iPython notebook had a separate element for the header that says "iPython." Some time ago, I inserted the following lines into my local custom.js file in order to hide this header (but not the associated toolbars):

```
$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
$('div#header').hide();});
```

In the new release, adding this code causes the entire toolbar/header assembly to be hidden. This messes up the calculation of the height of the space and causes the appearance of the white bar. Finding my local custom.js and commenting out these lines resolves the issue.

Comment: Aha, I followed this hack in the old version of IPython. Fixed now, Thanks!